# Отправка запроса через определенный ключ + проверка посещений

Tags: php, html, json

Интересует как добавить к своему сайту что-то вроде определенных ключей.
Выглядеть это должно по типу http://link.com/ex.php&key=QerfaA342D или отправка его post запросом.

Так же, хотелось бы посмотреть ip адреса которые переходят по ссылке.
Для каждого ключа определенный файл с ip адресами.
Заранее спасибо всем за помощь

Comment: Для чего вам использовать `POST` запрос и почему хотите хранить ip адреса в файлах?

Comment: У меня сайт, который работает для работы с программой.
Мне нужно, что-бы на сайт могла отправлять запросы только программа и ее копии(у других купивших лицензию)
Если отсниффать проект, можно увидеть запрос и использовать его в дальнейшем для своих целей, что очень мне не нравится.
Вы этом и замысел всей этой машенины :)

Comment: Авторизацию OAuth2 не рассматриваете?

Comment: @Mully, если можно выловить GET запрос, какие проблемы выловить POST? :)

Comment: У вас API(ваш сайт), программа которая обращается к нему, и вы хотите только чтобы вы и другие "копии ПО" могли отправлять запросы и получать на них ответы?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы читать значения ключей используйте глобальную переменную [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php). Это ассоциативный массив, где ключи - имена переменных, переданных в url

С адресом клиента немного сложнее. Их может быть, гм, несколько. Ситуация проясняется [там](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/getting-real-client-ip-address-in-php-2/)

```
function get_client_ip_server() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

    return $ipaddress;
}
```